# Visual Studio Unit Tests fails when running test without the debugger

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0, reflection

My unit tests fails when they get here:

```
var y = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                 .GetAssemblies()
                 .Where(a => !a.GlobalAssemblyCache)
                 .SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes()
                                   .Where(t => t.IsClass && typeof(ITypeRenderer).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
                 .ToArray();
```

But when I run the test with the debugger attached, it does not fail.

I guess it has to do something with reflection permissions and all that jazz, any idea?

The exception is:

> Initialization method MyUnitTestProject.UnitTest.Init threw exception.
>   System.NotSupportedException: System.NotSupportedException: The
>   invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly..

The exception happens at:

```
System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.GetExportedTypes()
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does it fail with when you run it outside the debugger?

Comment: since the line you're showing us isn't an assertion of some sort, presumably there's an error message. Otherwise, as @JaredPar says, what do you mean by the test failing at this line? (I presume it doesn't cause the universe to collapse in on itself, since you managed to post the question)

Comment: I added the exception message and type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the error message *does* say "The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly". Obviously, when you're running the tests outside of the debugger, something is causing a dynamic assembly to be created in the same AppDomain as where the tests are running.

Equally (hopefully) obviously, a check for [`IsDynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332812.aspx) to exclude such assemblies (in the same way that you exclude GAC assemblies) should avoid the error.